# Restart the connection

Tags: networking, ubuntu-gnome, restart

Sometimes, when I logout from my account in Ubuntu, my network connection stays disabled when I login again. Is there a way to restart the connection such that I see the little icon in the right-top corner of my laptop? In fact, that problem occur when I start `VPNoneclick`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe restarting the network-manager will help:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```